# How to disable android homepage

Tags: android, launcher

I use the automatic launch of my application when I turn on my ACER tablet Iconia one (6.0), but the android home page appears before for a few seconds.
Is it possible to run the application without showing android homepage ?
Regards,
François

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run the application without showing android homepage ?

Make your app *be* the "android homepage", by implementing a MAIN/HOME `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want the icon app on the Android Home Page ... I dont wan't to see Android Home Page before the App start's automatically ...

Comment: @François: "but I don't want the icon app on the Android Home Page" -- that is not what that `<intent-filter>` is for. That `<intent-filter>` is to declare your app as *being* a candidate for what you refer to as "the Android Home Page". "I dont wan't to see Android Home Page before the App start's automatically" -- the only way to guarantee that is for your app to *be* what you call "the Android Home Page".